# What is the easiest way to create a scrollable form for iOS

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I have been struggling with IB and auto layout and figure there must be an easier way to create a simple scrollable form with multiple fields on it.  The width can adjust to the device screen width (or in the case of the iPad to the details view of a split view.

The basic layout is simple a label and underneath a field (in some cases the field must have a minimum height) repeated for each attribute.

I think I must be doing something completely stupid or IB's autolayout is hopeless, I suspect the former.  In any event whatever I do in IB fields just adopt whatever constraints they feel like it seems.  Even when I set a constrain it seem IB just replaces it sometimes.

Currently I am using a view with a fixed height and width that fits the screen and laying out fields on this form, however its a complete nightmare having to pin every field in almost every direction.  And then IB complains about a million constraints that it can't satisfy.

Hopefully someone has a better way of doing this they are willing to share - perhaps it might be best just to write some code to set up the constraints rather than relying on IB ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are right UIScrollView and autolayout is not clear at first look. 
You have to understand that when you are adding layout constraints for a view inside scroll view, the superview is content view of scroll (not the view of the UIScrollView) that can be more or less then current view of the ScrollView in IB.

Comment: Yes I get that, I add items to the contentView which I try and set to a fixed height so I can lay out fields on it but it seems virtually impossible to then adjust contentView height once fields have been placed without them all moving again. I wish I knew what logic IB is applying in deciding it needs to move some fields and not others when they should all be pinned to top left.  Adjusting the height of their parent should not affect their positions.